# Retaining M5 bolts for bottle cages

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, accessories, preventative-maintenance, titanium

I have a Ti frame.

Alloy M5 bolts (they were greased) not working too well for me for holding the bottle cages - one seized / broke off, and I lost the boss/insert (?) when a mechanic drilled out the sheared-off bolt.

I understand that a light or medium loctite usually performs better than grease

However, are there any special considerations using Ti M5 bolts? (since in a moment of extravagance I have bought some, and currently awaiting delivery)

Comment: Strange, usually the forces on bottle cages are not that great. I think some people even use aluminium screws for bottle cages and steel screws of the same size are used for much greater loads (rear rack, stems …). Maybe you tightened too much, shearing off the head? Or maybe you tightened too little, allowing the cage to become slightly loose and rub against the screw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium is light, strong, and like aluminum, is corrosion resistant by virtue of the formation of an inert oxide layer on the outside.  As long as this oxide layer remains intact, a titanium part is very corrosion resistant and will not react to other metals. Thus,  grease applied to the titanium threads will prevent galling, which will expose the reactive titanium as this protective oxide layer gets stripped off.  Copper anti-seize grease seems to be the go-to product for the titaniums protection and prevents reactions between differing metals. [See this article on galling and titanium fasteners](https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/materials-and-grades/thread-galling.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear about your bike...

Titanium anti seize is what you need. Park Tool makes one and you can usually find other brands of anti seize for a bit less at an automotive parts store but you may end up with a lifetime supply as bikes use very little.

Comment: NoCo Rider - thanks for your input. Now you mention it I have a tube of ParkTool ASC-1 anti-seize compound - I assume that is the product you are referring to.   As a matter of interest, can you expand why that product is better than Loctite 242 - I want to ensure (i) M5 bolts stay in place, and (2) are then removable without undue difficulty with typical hand tools.  My understanding is that Loctite achieve both - is there some special property of Ti bolts that make a difference ?

Answer (score 1):

@peter If you use locktite make sure you DO NOT USE red. Use the blue.

Comment: Thanks for reminder - when I referred to 'light or medium' loctite I was thinking of '242' specifically